# From where to upload app binary file on App store

Tags: iphone, app-store

I have followed all the steps to upload my first application on "https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa"

at last i had uploaded the Large image & Screenshots.

I had not an option to upload the Binary file.

Now application status is "Waiting For Upload".

I am right now confuse about to upload my binary file, from where & how i can upload it?

is appliacation under review? is everything ok? or I will have to do any change?

Please, help me out, i am new to upload application.

All related helps are appreciated & thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please download a app called "Application Loader" on mac . and compile your code with the provisioning profile.

put login id and password of your itunes connect in Application Loader application.
it will  automatically ask for the .zip file of your first application Binary.

complete all formalities from itune connect.

Answer (score 4):

Once you installed the appropiate certificate and distribution profile you're ready to go.

Open XCode -> select your distribution certificate within Build Settings -> code signing

Then click on 'Product' button within the topbar -> Archive -> choose upload to Appstore

When you follow these steps your App should be submitted the right way.